# Limit of f(x) as x goes to a

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $I$ is an open interval which contains a. If $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(x) \rightarrow f(a)$, as $x \rightarrow a$, and if there exist numbers $M$ and $m$ such that $m <f(a) <M$, prove that there exist positive numbers $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$ such that :

$m+ \varepsilon < f(x) < M- \varepsilon$

So far I have tried to play around with inequalities using $|f(x)-f(a)| < \varepsilon$. But I haven't been able to get what I need.

Comment: $m+ \varepsilon < f(x) < M- \varepsilon$ for which $x$?

Answer (score 0):

The question is missing some quantifiers.  Presumably you want to prove that there are positive $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ such that $m + \epsilon < f(x) < M - \epsilon$ whenever $x$ satisfies $|x - a| < \delta$.

Unfortunately, like many statements in analysis, there are a lot of choices of $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ that will work, and so any proof that such $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ exist will involve making choices that have some amount of arbitrariness in them.  I will sketch an outline of how to make one choice below.

To get a sense of what is going on, it might help to sketch a graph of some continuous function $y = f(x)$, and pick a point $a$ on the $x$-axis, and draw some line $y = M$ with $M > f(a)$, and also some line $y = m$ with $m < f(a)$.  The task of this problem then has geometric meaning: we want to show that there is some positive $\epsilon$ with the property that, by restricting ourselves to a small enough $x$-interval around $a$, we can ensure that the graph of $y = f(x)$ stays more than $\epsilon$ away from *both* lines $y = M$ and $y = m$.  Hopefully, after you do this, it will become clear that such a choice of $\epsilon$ should be possible--- and also that the choice must depend, in some sense, on how close both $M$ and $m$ are to $f(a)$ (i.e.: the closer they are, the smaller $\epsilon$ will have to be).  Once you have this intuition, all that's left is to figure out how to make some semi-arbitrary choices in what to plug into the given hypotheses, so that as a consequence, you get a proof of what you want.  (This is the "playing around with inequalities" that you refer to, where you seem to be stuck.)

I will sketch one way of doing this below.  (Spoiler alert?)

Let $k$ denote the smaller of $M - f(a)$ and $f(a) - m$ (or their common value if they are equal).  Since $m < f(a) < M$, the number $k$ is positive, and hence $k/2$ is positive.  Putting $k/2$ into the definition of "$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a)$" you learn that there is $\delta > 0$ with the property that whenever $|x - a| < \delta$ one has $|f(x) - f(a)| < k/2$.

With that in mind, fix any $x$ with $|x - a| < \delta$.  Since $|f(x) - f(a)| < k/2$, we deduce that $f(x) - f(a) < k/2$, which implies that $f(x) - f(a) + k/2 < k/2 + k/2 = k$, which (since $k \leq M - f(a)$) implies that $f(x) - f(a) + k/2 < M - f(a)$, which implies that $f(x) + k/2 < M$, which implies that $f(x) < M - k/2$.

See if you can show (for similar reasons) that whenever $|x - a| < \delta$ one will also have $f(x) > m + k/2$.  This would finish the exercise, as it proves that one can take $\epsilon$ to be $k/2$, and $\delta$ to be the positive number that the definition of "$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a)$" provides when $k/2$ is "plugged into" it.